# web site publishing problem

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have win server 2003 and IIS 6. After publish my web app to IIS and set port 8080 I can't see web site

UPDATE:
 I solve my problem with connect to port 8080, after type http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:8080/ I see this

Thursday, August 19, 2010  9:26 AM        App_Data
Thursday, August 19, 2010  9:26 AM         bin
Thursday, August 19, 2010  9:26 AM         Content
Thursday, August 19, 2010  9:11 AM        97 Global.asax
Thursday, August 19, 2010  9:26 AM         Scripts
Thursday, August 19, 2010  9:26 AM         Views
Thursday, August 19, 2010  9:11 AM        11799 Web.config

how can I view my site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a combination of the following issues:

1. directory browsing is enabled
2. no default document is specified
3. possibly the incorrect version of .net is associated with the website.

It looks like you are using MVC (Views directory) - is your site configured correctly for MVC and does your server have all the right frameworks installed and bound to IIS (you may need to use `aspnet_regiis` for each of the required frameworks)

if you created the site using visual studio try using its "Deploy Website" feature as it should ensure all the settings for your site are correct for it to be displayed.

Have a look here http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx for an IIS 6.0 MVC walk through.

Comment: Yes I am using MVC. I need extension for aspnet_regiis. How you mean "Deploy Website"

Comment: it depends on the framework version but normally its 

`c:\windows\microsoft.Net\framework\vx.xxxx\aspnet_regiis -iru`

what version of visual studio do you use? VS 2008 or VS 2010?

Comment: I found aspnet_regiis. If I add them to wild card mapping or application mapping

Comment: you run each of the aspnet_regiis commands for the frameworks you need in a command prompt, you dont add a mapping.  
open a command prompt to `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` then run the command `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

do the above for each of the frameworks you are using

Comment: I have big problem. i run your comand but problem is still there. On my home page i can see only list of files, not a web site

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx this has a walk throuh on getting MVC running on IIS6. added to the main answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Does the server have an active firewall?

Have you checked IIS if the website you published is created and active?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a default webpage.
However your list does not show any ".aspx" page so it is likely that your publication went wrong.